# Research profiles descriptors used by the European Commission

Tags: job, europe, reference-request

The European Commission has drafted so-called Research profiles descriptors.  I understand that this is an attempt to uniformly describe researchers' career stages in a way agnostic to particular countries or sectors (academia, industry, NGO, etc.)

https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/europe/career-development/training-researchers/research-profiles-descriptors

Is there some resource summarizing equivalences between this system and, say, the system used in the academia in the US (postdocs, Assistant Professors, Associate Professors, Full Professors)?

(Normally one doesn't have to deal with this bureaucratic neologism, but their job listing uses this classification.)

Comment: A quick read seems to indicate that R1 is a student, R2 generally seems to cover a postdoc, and R3 and R4 are what one would expect for various levels of professor. But, the research profile levels are not university job titles - their purpose is different.